# Wpf DataGrid RowStyle How use either Image or Brush for Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a RowStyle defined in xaml within a Style targeting a DataGrid:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
<!-- Bunch of other setters -->
<Setter Property="RowStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridRowBgConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="IsThis" />
                        <Binding Path="IsThat" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Some DataGrids will need a RowStyle that uses an image for the background, to be shown when a certain property is true.
I have modified the multibinding to pass the datacontext as the third value, and modified the converter to examine the DC to determine if an image is required.
I can't figure out how to structure the xaml, though.
UPDATE:
This seems to work, except to set TwoWay binding, I need specify a path.

```
  <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ImageBrush Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DataGridRowImageConverter}}"  />
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

How does the binding path get set up to bind to the DC (the equivalent of `<Binding />`)?  The binding in the xaml above gives me the necessary DC; how do I express the same thing using the Path?
Thanks for any insights....

Answer (score 0):

You cant have more than 1 setter for the same property.  You can use a DataTrigger on the style to set the background to an ImageBrush according to properties from the DataContext.  It would look something like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <!-- Bunch of other setters -->
    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridRowBgConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="IsThis" />
                        <Binding Path="IsThat" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyToIndicateImageBackground}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="YourImage.jpg"/> 
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We don't know the property name that will trigger the use of the image, nor the imageSource, until the datagrid is created.  In your example, can the DataTrigger bind to the DC?  I'll experiment with it...

Comment: You should be able to bind to the DC.  You would then need a converter to return true/false on the binding for the DataTrigger